# How do I add a string to an element inside a list?

Tags: python

I'm learning lists and in order to get a better understanding I thought I'd apply some basic concepts I've learned so far.

What I'm attempting to do through my code is to add a new name to my **list_of_Names** and have it add a last name automatically. This is where I'm stuck.
My solution was using " Washington".join(newPerson) but that clearly doesn't work.

And please don't mind the efficiency of the code, I'm creating a new list just so I can apply the pop() command in a new scenario.

Also I've looked up similar issues, please don't tell me to use the **map()** command if it is somehow possible.

```py
list_of_Names = ["Wallace Washington"]

def addNewMemeber(name):
    newPerson = []
    newPerson.append(name)
    " Washington".join(newPerson)
    list_of_Names.append(newPerson.pop())

addNewMemeber("William")

print(list_of_Names, end=", ")
```

Comment: To concatenate `name` and `" Washington"`, you can simply use `name + " Washington"`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with making `newPerson` and poping it? What's wrong with `list_of_names.append(name_of_new_member + " Washington")`?

Comment: If you were thinking of using `join`, you apparently misunderstood what it does. You could use it like this: `" ".join([name, "Washington"])`

Comment: The point of using pop is just that, just so I can use a new command in a new scenario. Thank you for the solution, I've apparently misunderstood what join does and need to re-read the command again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). I have rewritten your code again to get your desired result:-

```
list_of_Names = ["Wallace Washington"]

def addNewMemeber(name):
    name = name + " Washington" 
    # If surname is fixed. If not then store surnames in a list and then perform logic by if-else.
    list_of_Names.append(name)

addNewMemeber("William")
print(list_of_Names, end=", ")
```

2). Same Solution with `join()` method.

```
list_of_Names = ["Wallace Washington"]

def addNewMemeber(name):
    l = []
    l.append(name)
    l.append("Washington")
    name = " ".join(l)
    # Join is used to convert list into string.
    list_of_Names.append(name)

addNewMemeber("William")
print(list_of_Names, )
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I understand better now. I seem to have misunderstood what join does. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a string to the list `list_of_names`. There is no point in the `newPerson` list

```
def addNewMemeber(name):
    list_of_Names.append(f'{name} Washington')
```

In order to use the `pop` command for the sake of it, theres 2 problems.

1. Your call to join doesn't save the result to a variable
2. Join doesn't make any sense.

So if you really want to add to the `newPerson` list, then don't use join whatsoever..

```
def addNewMemeber(name):
    newPerson = [f'{name} Washington']
    list_of_Names.append(newPerson.pop())
```

Comment: You didn't even bother reading the point of it did you? Thank you for this solution nevertheless.

Comment: @Coderoe - "What I'm attempting to do through my code is to add a new name to my list_of_Names and have it add a last name automatically. "  What exactly did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about join function [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/).

I think the code you are looking for is as follows:

```
list_of_Names = ["Wallace Washington"]

def addNewMemeber(name):
    name += ' Washington'
    list_of_Names.append(name)


addNewMemeber("x")
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir.